# Adicionar elemento em Lista (Arraylist)

Tags: java, array

Estou com problema para adicionar valores que estão em uma Lista chamada Processos para a lista Aptos. Sempre mostra apenas o último processo, e de forma duplicada. Mesmo assim retira todos os processos anteriores.

Código abaixo:

```
public void verificaTodosProcessosAptos(){
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<FilaProcessos.size();i++){
       if(FilaProcessos.get(i).getTempoCriacao()<TSP){
           saiDeProcessoParaAptos();
           i--;
       }
   }
}

public void saiDeProcessoParaAptos(){
       //apto=FilaAptos.get(indiceAptos);
       processo=FilaProcessos.get(0);
       apto.setPid(processo.getPid());
       apto.setNome(processo.getNome());
       apto.setTempoCriacao(processo.getTempoCriacao());
       apto.setTempoExecucao(processo.getTempoExecucao());
       if (TSF == 0) 
            apto.setEsperaFila(0);
       else
            apto.setEsperaFila(TSP - apto.getTempoCriacao());
       apto.setSaidaFila(apto.getTempoCriacao() + apto.getEsperaFila());
       TSF=apto.getSaidaFila();
       armazenarFilaApto(apto);
       indiceAptos++;
       excluirFilaProcessos(processo);
       indiceProcesso--;
   }

public void armazenarFilaApto(Aptos a){
        FilaAptos.add(a);
}
```

Não sei se conseguiram entender, qualquer coisa esclareço as dúvidas sobre minha pergunta.

Comment: Pode colocar em código? Não consigo ver a imagem.

Comment: como eu formato o código aqui?

Comment: Dê 4 espaços no inicio da linha, que ele já faz o 'resto'

Comment: no medoto "saiDeProcessoParaAptos()", você está pegando sempre o FilaProcessos.get(0). Não aconselho você tentar manipular o índice de um for. Isso também pode atrapalhar!

Comment: Também acharia interessante que colocasse o código e não uma foto!

Comment: Se for muito grande, quatro espaços em cada linha do código, se for pequeno, coisa de um método ou palavra reservada, use Shift+´ antes e depois do trecho em destaque.

Answer (score 1):

Eu reescrevi o seu código, simplificando alguns passos e funcionou Ok, resultando na saída esperada e não apresentando apenas o último elemento da `FilaProcessos`, confira:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    static List<String> filaProcessos = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> filaAptos = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        filaProcessos.add("um");
        filaProcessos.add("dois");
        filaProcessos.add("tres");

        verificaTodosProcessosAptos();

        for (String s : filaAptos) { 
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public static void verificaTodosProcessosAptos(){
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<filaProcessos.size();i++){
            saiDeProcessoParaAptos();
            i--;
        }
    }

    public static void saiDeProcessoParaAptos(){
        String processo = filaProcessos.get(0);
        String apto = processo;

        armazenarFilaApto(apto);
        //indiceAptos++;
        filaProcessos.remove(processo);
        //indiceProcesso--;
    }

    public static void armazenarFilaApto(String a){
        filaAptos.add(a);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olha amigo eu tive um problema parecido com esse e a falha estava na falta de instância, um novo objeto a cada iteração, por exemplo, finalizou um ciclo do `for` eu tenho que dar um `new` nos objetos da classe.

Pelo que percebo você está usando variáveis globais, não é? Então da uma verificada aonde você está instanciando o objeto apto ou outro que esteja usando.

Comment: Acho que era isto mesmo Maique. Pelo menos deu uma melhorada quando criei a nova instância. Valeu

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia.
Seus métodos estão um pouco confusos, comece por simplificá-los. Vou comentar o código para tentar explicar.

```
public void verificaTodosProcessosAptos(){
   //Este metodo faz a mesma coisa que você quer fazer, mas sem indice (você não precisa dele)
   for(Processo proc : FilaProcessos){
       if(proc.getTempoCriacao()<TSP){
           saiDeProcessoParaAptos(prc);
       }
   }
}

//Neste método, você não precisa pegar o FilaProcessos.get(0), basta passar o processo por parâmetro, acredito que seja isto que você quer.

public void saiDeProcessoParaAptos(Processo proc){

       apto.setPid(proc.getPid());
       apto.setNome(proc.getNome());
       apto.setTempoCriacao(proc.getTempoCriacao());
       apto.setTempoExecucao(proc.getTempoExecucao());
       if (TSF == 0) 
            apto.setEsperaFila(0);
       else
            apto.setEsperaFila(TSP - apto.getTempoCriacao());
       apto.setSaidaFila(apto.getTempoCriacao() + apto.getEsperaFila());
       TSF=apto.getSaidaFila();
       armazenarFilaApto(apto);
       indiceAptos++;
       excluirFilaProcessos(proc);
       indiceProcesso--;
   }
```

Daqui em diante você deve ir testando o seu código, se tiver dificuldades em encontrar o erro apenas com logs, tente Depurar o seu projeto!

Se tiver dificuldades em entender o que eu escrevi vai pedindo que na medida do possível eu respondo.

Abraços

Answer (score 0):

Se aptos e processos são duas listas que possui os mesmos tipo de valores você pode utilizar:

```
aptos.addAll(processos);
```